# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation already exists on OenBSD vps

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery

I am getting this error. I tried with migrate --fake default but it doesn't seems to be working. attached is output of "python manage.py migrate" My set up is Django 1.6 + celery3.1.12 + postgresql + gunicorn on OneBSD VPS.

```
Running migrations for users:


- Migrating forwards to 0007_auto__del_field_profile_weekly_digest__del_field_profile_daily_digest_.
 > users:0001_initial
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "users_user" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "last_login" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "is_active" boolean NOT NULL, "is_admin" boolean NOT NULL, "is_staff" boolean NOT NULL, "type" integer NOT NULL, "status" integer NOT NULL, "new_messages" integer NOT NULL, "badges" integer NOT NULL, "score" integer NOT NULL, "full_score" integer NOT NULL, "flair" varchar(15) NOT NULL, "site_id" integer NULL)
The error was: relation "users_user" already exists

Error in migration: users:0001_initial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 220, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 254, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 329, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 133, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration, database)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 114, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration, database)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 84, in run_migration
    migration_function()
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/biostar/apps/users/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 28, in forwards
    ('site', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(to=orm['sites.Site'], null=True)),
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 47, in _cache_clear
    return func(self, table, *args, **opts)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 361, in create_table
    "columns": ', '.join([col for col in columns if col]),
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 282, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/jay/biostar-central/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_user" already exists
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` doesn't work, you could try to delete  migration folder from your app and create new one by:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 13):

This works for me:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Comment: No change are made on the db, the newly created table are not added

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but I ran into this problem in Django 1.11. I use a tables-django model that requires another TableModel that depends on previous model. I had to remove these from my inital migration.

So check your migration file in

```
app/migrations/some_migration.py
```

There is likely a table referenced twice.